# How to know which argument of function is a column in the table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gis, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL with GisT and PostGIS, I want to find geometries who have distance within a threshold to a query geometry. So first, I should expand the bounding box of the query, and second , I should pass the expanded bounding box into the GisT Index.

I think the linguistic meaning of the two queries : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DWithin(querygeom, table.col)` , and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DWithin(table.col, querygeom)` is the same, where tabel.col is a column of geometry, and querygeom is a static geometry i pass in. However, as I have a GisT index on table.col, I want to always expand the query, but not the column, in order to use the index. (If I understand right, if I expand the boxes inside that column, I could not use the index?)

Is that any way for it? For example, using rule to rewrite the query?

Comment: "*I want to always expand the query, but not the column*" - that statement makes no sense (at least to me). The parameters to [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_DWithin.html) are just "values" - none of them being "a table" or a "query".

Comment: Could you elaborate on `query` being a parameter of `ST_DWithin`? Do you mean a subquery that returns a single geometry?

Comment: @JimJones   sorry for misleading, i'm just use the 'query' to stand for another geometry that I pass into the function...question modified.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  err, by it I mean a column of geometries

Comment: @Bobi.Liu the documentation says `This function call will automatically include a bounding box comparison that will make use of any indexes that are available on the geometries.` so I believe you're good. However, if you're concerned that the index is not being used, please add the `explain analyze` of your query to the question and we can discuss it in more details.

Comment: @JimJones thanks a lot, i find that i misunderstand its logic

Answer (score 0):

I think I find this answer... 
It uses a symmetric fomulation:

```
'SELECT $1 OPERATOR(@extschema@.&&) @extschema@.ST_Expand($2,$3) AND $2 OPERATOR(@extschema@.&&) @extschema@.ST_Expand($1,$3) AND @extschema@._ST_DWithin($1, $2, $3)'
```

so either side could use that index(with higher computation cost, i guess)